# Rotating the Node chain to left n times and returning the new head of the Node chain not working as expected

Tags: python, nodes

I am to write a function called `rotate(head, n)` that takes the head of a Node chain and an integer, `n`, as parameters. The function must rotate the Node chain to the left n times and return the new head of the Node chain.

For example, given the following Node chain:
`A -> B -> C -> None`

Rotating left one time would produce:
`B -> C -> A -> None`
I am to keep in mind that the node chain will contain at least three elements and n can be any non-negative integer.

Here is my `Node` class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self.__data = data
        self.__next = next_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.__data

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.__data = data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.__next

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.__next = new_next
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__data} -> {self.__next}'
```

This is my `rotate()` function:

```
def rotate(head, n):
    if (n == 0):
        return
    current = head
    while (current.get_next() != None):
        current = current.get_next()
   
    current.next = head
    current = head
    for i in range(n - 1):
        current = current.get_next()
   
    head = current.get_next()
    current = None
    return head
```

Test:

```
chain = from_list(['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(chain)
chain = rotate(chain, 1)
print(chain)
```

Expected Ouput:

```
A -> B -> C -> None
B -> C -> A -> None
```

Received Ouput:

```
A -> B -> C -> None
B -> C -> None
```

Test2:

```
chain = from_list(['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(chain)
chain = rotate(chain, 2)
print(chain)
```

Expected Output2:

```
A -> B -> C -> None
C -> A -> B -> None
```

Gotten Ouput2:

```
C -> A -> B -> None
A -> B -> C -> None
C -> None
```

TEST:

```
chain = from_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
print(chain)
chain = rotate(chain, 0)
print(chain)
```

EXPECT:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> None
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> None
```

GOT:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> None
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got three small bugs, here's the correct version:

```
def rotate(head, n):
    if (n == 0):
        return head # fixed
    current = head
    while (current.get_next() != None):
        current = current.get_next()

    current.set_next(head) # fixed
    current = head
    for i in range(n - 1):
        current = current.get_next()
   
    head = current.get_next()
    current.set_next(None) # fixed
    return head
```

Comment: But even if I fix this, my code is still not working for one test case, I have edited my question.

Comment: Edited my answer, look for the three `# fixed`s